# Deploying a WPF application to multiple desktops in the enterprise

Tags: wpf, deployment, permissions, acl

I am in the process of deploying a .NET applications across multiple desktops in the enterprise. Not everyone has administrative access and the application does not do anything special requiring the same.

However launching the app itself I am getting the following exception:

Error parsing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config. Parser returned error 0X80070005.

It looks like the application and/or the user does not have access to machine.config. I tried this on my personal laptop (Windows 7).

Despite being a administrator, thanks to UAC, I confronted the same exception too. How do we solve this issue?

Comment: `ClickOnce` will resolve your deployment problems. It resolved ours, and we deploy to end users, not just inside a controlled enterprise environment.

Comment: Does this support WPF applications, HighCore?

Comment: Yep, our application is a WPF 4.0 application.

Comment: Can you shed some light into creating a ClickOnce installer? I am trying to see if they are available in Visual Studio. I see a Installshield Limited, Web Setup, CAB project etc. but not ClickOnce.

Comment: `Visual Studio 2010 -> Solution Explorer -> Right Click your WPF project (the EXE) -> Publish...` You can find more info in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. But I am confronting the same error again. I published the application to a IIS virtual directory. Now when I browse that virtual directory as http://lavanyadeepak.mydomain.com/wpfinstaller/publish.htm, I get a beautifully formatted page with 'Install Link'. Clicking the install link again pops up the same message (from dfsvc.exe).

Comment: I just saw the permissions on machine.config. It has administrator and system only. Any setup issues?